# Flex items - how to make the items only take up as much space as needed even when the text breaks into a new line?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

https://jsfiddle.net/Lf4dp5tj/

I have a very simple example of flex items:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="sidebar">
    test tes test
  </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
    test tes test
  </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
    test tes test
  </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
    test tes test
  </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
    test tes test
  </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
    test tes test
  </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
    test tes test
  </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
    test tes test
  </div>
</div>


#container {
  display:flex;
}
#sidebar {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

When the text isn't wrapping into the next line, the items only take up as much horizontal width as necessary:

[image]

But when the line breaks, the boxes take up more horizontal width than necessary:
[image]

How can I make the boxes take up only as much space as needed even when the text wraps into the next line? I still want to use `display: flex` on the container.